# How to create a right to left UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I want to create a right to left UITableView.
right now I have the left to right table view.

I would like to know if there is an easy way to transfrom the left to right table into right to left using the latest iphone SDK?

I've tried the textAlignment on my custom table view cell but with no success.

Thanks

Comment: Clarify your question. You want the text to be right aligned, or the words to read from right to left, or the UITableView to transition from Right to Left?

Comment: I need all UITableview to transition from left to right.
for right-to-left languages.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is a table that when click will slide the opposite way. Instead of FirstTable sliding out to the left and SecondTable sliding IN from the right you want it to slide the other way. This will be a more difficult task.

On the other hand about having the text on the other side of the table:

Make sure that your cells are being defined with default style

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Then all you have to to is align the text in the textLabel to the right:

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

For iOS7, use `cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;`

Hope this helped,

Seb Kade