# UITableView support for right to left languages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

how to change a table view layout to be from right to left (including its transition to a detail view: the transition must also be from right to left) ?
thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For view transition you can check the following apple sample code:[View Transition](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ViewTransitions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007411)

Answer (score 3):

There is no single property  nigher in `UITableView` nor `UITableViewCell` to change the right to left OR left to right, If you want it in your application, you will have make an custom `UITableViewCell` and layout the views (components of your cell) right to left.

Check the below SO post

[Right to Left Alignment for UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677988/right-to-left-alignment-for-uitableview)

[How to create a right to left UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543858/how-to-create-a-right-to-left-uitableview)